# How to keep my Unity build from minimizing when I switch focus to an app on another monitor?

Tags: unity, fullscreen

I have a multi-monitor setup. We are doing a lot of demos right now.  I have my meeting controls on one screen and my Unity build on another one that is shared.  When I click anything on any other monitor, the Unity build minimizes.  My build was initially set to "Fullscreen Window" but in an attempt to resolve this issue I have set it to "Maximized Window" but this did not fix the issue.

[image]

How can I interact with apps on another monitor without minimizing my game?

Answer (score 1):

The "Visible In Background" option did exactly what I needed. Not sure why I didn't notice this first.